# Resolve with $state throws unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

I'm using **ui-router** to handle my apps states. I need to use resolve to ensure that a settings value is there when the controller is loaded. I started by making a very simple dummy:

```
  .state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    resolve: {
      simpleObj: function(){
        return {value: 'simple!'};
      }
    },
    controller: 'DashboardController',
    template: '<dashboard></dashboard>',
  });
```

In the controller I inject this like I would any other dependency:

```
angular
.module('flowlens')
.controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

DashboardController.$inject = ['simpleObj'];

function DashboardController(simpleObj){
  var vm = this;
  activate();

  function activate(){}
}
```

However this throws an `unknown provider error` on the `simpleObj` This code is based on the example code on the ui-router git repo so it should work.

According to others this typically happens when you use ng-controller on your template but my template contains no such thing:

```
%h2 Dashboard
%hr
%pre {{ $root.currentUser | json }}

.card.card-block
  %my-input{type: "contact", model: "selected_contact", placeholder:    "Choose Contact", allow-new: "true"}
  Selected:
  %pre {{ selected_contact | json }}
  %h2 Settings {{ $root.settings }}
```

There should be no need to use deferred to resolve this promise as it's just returning a simple value - correct?

What's the issue here?

---

**EDIT** Heres a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9ZvNdNXtxcFNofbdIeCe?p=preview) detailing what's going on.

---

Thanks to imbalind for the help. Here's an updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nWZbHwPEgDsmXREvNXB7?p=info) of it working. Check the console to see the value getting printed.

Comment: Code looks fine i think something small mismatch

Comment: there's a typo in the controller name 'FlDashboardController'

Comment: @NitsanBaleli sorry that isn't the problem that was me trying to remove a prefix. I've edited it now

Comment: Why don't you try to replicate this in a plunker? Usually this help me fix typos and other bugs and, if it doesn't help you, it will help others to find the problem faster!

Comment: @imbalind Was in the middle of it when you commented - see my edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you referenced the `DashboardController` twice in two different places:

1. inside the `$stateProvider`, where you add a resolve for `simpleObj`.
2. inside `dashboard` directive, where it cannot have a clue about what `simpleObj` is.

The error (IMHO) is having the same controller used for different things. You should have two different controllers.

If you need to access `simpleObj` from both of them you should think about making a service out of it.

**EDIT**: [Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/db7X1OcXkiFc0TCHneA2?p=preview) your plunker edited so to avoid the error. Logic is missing.

Comment: That worked - thanks. I re-edited the plunkr with your suggestions incorporated. The simple value now gets printed to the console fine - see my edit for the link